# Getting the reference to a duplicate in a Set

Tags: java, set, duplicates, hashset

I have a Set object and I use this set to ensure that when I add an element to it that already exists in the set, it's not added. This is the easy part, just use `Set.add();` But after this is done I need the reference to the object in the Set.

What I essentially mean is having a `.add()` that doesn't return a boolean, but the actual object you tried to add (if it wasn't added, the one in the set). Is there already a Set implementation that does this, or do I have to write my own?

At the moment I used a `Set.add()` and if it returns false I use an iterator to look for the one in the set. Although this works, I find it ugly. Especially when using the HashSet implementation which should be able to find the object a lot faster using hashcodes. Any ideas?

EDIT: Wow, lots of answers in a relatively short time, thanks. Ok, so what I'm trying to do is create a certain datastructure that loads data from some place and creates objects from it. This data might contain duplicates, and this wouldn't be a problem if I used a set and just needed this one set, but the datastructure needs to add references to these unique objects to other objects in the datastructure, therefore I need the references to the (unique) objects in the set. Also, I can't just not load the data that is already contained in the set, because there is more (unique) data linked to it, which is also added, together with a reference to that data that was already contained in the set. For illustration purposes (because the above explanation is far from clear) I'll give an example here:

Data:

```
foo     bar
1       3
1       4
2       5
```

Datastructure:

```
Set<Foo> totalFooSet  
Set<Bar> totalBarSet
```

Foo:

```
sometype data
Set<Bar> barSet
```

Bar:

```
sometype data
Set<Foo> fooSet
```

This is sort of like a many-to-many relation.

I'm not sure if there is some major design flaw here, I've looked it over with some other people and we can't figure out how to do this differently. I like the idea of using the HashMap, so I'll create a subclass and add an addAndReturn() function to it.

Comment: but if you're adding an element and `add` returns `false`, then you **know** that the duplicate element is the one you was trying to add!

Comment: Unless you are seriously raping the contract of `Object.equals()` there is no need for this as the object that will not be added to a Set is the same object as the one already in the set. Just use the object you already have. If you managed to break equals() you should resort to some other methods, e.g. using a `Map`.

Comment: Could you explain the use case for such a scenario?  I would be interested to know why you need the reference to the original object?

Comment: One use case (don't know if its the one of the asker) is to save memory by replacing several equal instances of a class by one single instance. This is called "interning". `String.intern()` is a method that does this (but just for strings).

Comment: If i interpret you correctly: Your objects implement equals(), so there is a possibility that there are 2 different objects which are equal to each other by equals() but they are not identical in terms of reference-identity, right?

Comment: @quaylar yes, that is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to Sean's answer (which I upvoted), but possibly more reusable.

```
public class HashMapBackedSet<T> extends HashMap<T,T>{
    public T add( T toAdd ){
        T existing = get( toAdd );
        if( existing != null ){
            return existing;
        }
        put( toAdd, toAdd );
        return toAdd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

(As @AlexR says, I'm assuming that you want a reference to the *previous* object equal to the one you are trying to add now)

Instead of using a Set, try using a HashMap with the same object as a key and a value. Then you can do the following:

```
Foo objectToAdd = //obtained the normal way
Map<Foo,Foo> psuedoSet = //this is stored somewhere

Foo result = psuedoSet.get(objectToAdd);
if (result == null) {
    pseudoSet.put(objectToAdd, objectToAdd);
    result = objectToAdd;
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, if the element you just tried to add is already contained in the set, you want the instance which is already in the set (which is *equal* to the one added, but not necessarily *identical*)?

This behavior is provided by the [interners](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interner.html) of the [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library:

```
Interner<Object> interner = Interners.newStrongInterner();
Object objectInSet = interner.intern(otherObject);
```

Unfortunately, interners do not provide any other methods like iterating over their contained values, so using them as a set replacement may not be possible for you.

Another option would be a `HashMap<T, T>` where you store a mapping from each object to itself. Then you can get the reference to the already contained object easily by calling `get()`. If you don't mind that the object is always overridden, just call `put()` which returns exactly the object you want (the previously stored object).

Comment: +1 for contrasting _identity_ with _equality_, the latter of which  @FinalArt has overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Set cannot contain duplicate entries. The purpose of set is not to do this.
As far as I understand you want to get reference to the *previous* object identical to one that you are trying to add now. 
You do not have to iterate the set to find this object. Just user `oldObject = set.get(newObject)`.

This operation is as fast as getting array element by index.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html Unfortunately, Set doesn't have a get(blah) method.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your set in a class that returns the object when you call add?